# Insert rows returned from table valued function if it does not already exist in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert rows returned from a table valued function into a base table only if the id in the row of the returned value does not already exist in the table. The function that I'm cross applying returns a table of IDs based on the input ID.

Here's a simplified version of what I had:

```
insert into @MainTable 
select FT.ID, FT.Name, FT.ParentID
from ( select T2.ID from @Table2 T2 where T2.UserID = @UserID and...) A
cross apply functionName(A.ID) FT 
where not exists ( select 1 from @MainTable MT where MT.ID = FT.ID )
```

Table2 might look like this e.g.

| ID |
| --- |
| 100 |
| 200 |

and results from the function would look like this:
from function(100)

| ID | Name | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | null |
| 102 | B | 100 |
| 103 | C | 100 |
| 104 | D | 100 |

and from function(200)

| ID | Name | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | E | null |
| 100 | A | 200 |
| 120 | F | 200 |

What should be inserted into @MainTable

| ID | Name | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | null |
| 102 | B | 100 |
| 103 | C | 100 |
| 104 | D | 100 |
| 200 | E | null |
| 120 | F | 200 |

but the duplicate record with ID 100 is inserted anyway - i only care about inserting the first instance returned and ignore any further duplicate IDs even if the parent is different

I thought this would check each row returned by the function before inserting that the id does not already exist in the main table but it seems to ignore that and duplicate IDs still exist in the resulting table. I'm not sure if using distinct would work as I want to keep the row already in the table and discard the new duplicate row only.

It seems like the 'if not exists' check only applies the check to the rows returned from the function once and then inserts them all, but the values returned from the function may contain duplicates so I need it to check if the exists in the table for each row before insertion

Comment: And please provide your desired results - its not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Best practice is to list the columns your are inserting into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like the 'if not exists' check only applies the check to the rows returned from the function once and then inserts them all

Correct, its applying the check *before* it carries out the insert. If you want to ensure you don't insert further duplicates, you need to check the data you are about to insert.

You can apply a distinct check before you insert using the `ROW_NUMBER()` method e.g.

```
with cte1 as (
  select FT.ID, FT.[Name], FT.ParentID
    , row_number() over (partition by ID order by [Name]) RowNum
  from @Table2 A
  cross apply functionName(A.ID) FT 
  where not exists (select 1 from @MainTable MT where MT.ID = FT.ID)
)
insert into @MainTable (Id, [Name], ParentID)
select ID, [Name], ParentID
from cte
where RowNum = 1
group by ID, [Name], PatentID;
```

Comment: sorry, i simplified it a bit too much - i updated the original post with clearer details of what's going on

Comment: Unfortunately I answered the question as asked... have a go and see if you can use the same logic to solve your new problem. I'm out of time.

Comment: Ok try that... Found a spare minute